# Node passport-jwt extracting wrong user from token

Tags: node.js, passport.js, jwt

I am experiencing a strange bug or error in my code.
I have setup an auth api on node server, using passportjs as my middleware and passport-jwt as my strategy.

My passport setup looks like this

```
//add jwt strategy to passport
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
var ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

var User = require('../models/user');
var configDB = require('../config/database');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    var opts = {};
    opts.secretOrKey = configDB.secret;
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
        //find user with give jwt payload id
        User.findOne({
            id: jwt_payload.id
        }, function(err, user) {
            if(err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if(user) {
                done(null, user);
            } else {
                done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }));
};
```

then, my protected route:

```
apiRoutes.get('/account', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), function(req, res) { 

    console.log(req.user.nickname); //returns user1 no matter what JWT I supply with request
    console.log(jwt.decode(getToken(req.headers), configDB.secret)).nickname; //decodes user from token correctly
    ..do other stuff
});
```

Why does passport sets req.user with the same user everytime, no matter what Token I supply in Authorization header ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved,
this line caused problem:

```
User.findOne({
  id: jwt_payload.id
...
```

both ids should be _id
:)

Answer (score 2):

@BlueBallPanda, to answer your question with passport.js JWT authentication strategy I would like to show the structure of **JWT_PAYLOAD** object that you use in line:

```
...  
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) { 
...
}));
```

As a reference example here below is output of JWT_PAYLOAD object, you can see its structure, which can actually easily confuse:

```
JWT_PAYLOAD:  { '$__':
   { strictMode: true,
     selected: {},
     getters: {},
     _id: '7987930e36333b5634bb5577',
     wasPopulated: false,
     activePaths: { paths: [Object], states: [Object], stateNames: [Array] },
     pathsToScopes: {},
     emitter: { domain: null, _events: {}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: 0 } },
  isNew: false,
  _doc:
   { __v: 0,
     password: '$2a$10$12GRB1vGbkl3XfGY.r81SuASyK/cfsp85fk92B3N6eSRO6GVy1TSW',
     email: 'example.mail@email.com',
     _id: '7987930e36333b5634bb5577' },
  '$init': true,
  iat: 1502061031,
  exp: 1502071111 }
```

So to grab the user ID in order to extract from DB on JWT check, 
just reference it like that:

```
 User.findOne({
        id: jwt_payload.$__._id
    }
```

or like that:

```
 User.findOne({
        id: jwt_payload.$__._doc._id
    }
```

Hope this clears out the buggy situation you have experienced.

Comment: Thanks, was not really a bug, I just didnt realize that mongoose generates the model IDs as '_id' instead of 'id'... But anyway, some really helpful data in the payload, will check it out next time I work with it thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with this function:

```
var JwtStrategy = require(‘passport-jwt’).Strategy,
ExtractJwt = require(‘passport-jwt’).ExtractJwt;

// load up the user model
var User = require(‘../models/user’);
var config = require(‘../config/database’); // get db config file

module.exports = function(passport) {
    var opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
        done(null, jwt_payload._doc);
    }));
};
```

_doc have the data user.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `where` clause solved my problem:

```
let user = await User.findOne({ where: { id: JWTPayloads.id } });
```