# jwt payload is the same each time i register a new user

Tags: express, jwt

i'm new to this . i've followed along with this tutorial //https://devdactic.com/restful-api-user-authentication-1/

so it's all working , adduser is hashing , login is returning a jwt login a new user is returned to jwt.encode in route /api/login and a new jwt is returned

I want to get the user details from a protect route, for example

server.get('/api/routeThatNeedsJWTToken', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function(req, res){
    res.json({'Success! You can not see this without a token':'bla', user: req.user});
  });

Here the req.user returned is always the first user i registered. i need the one matching the jwt, the users id or name .

any help appreciated or i'm thinking about starting from scratch and going this way https://www.sitepoint.com/using-json-web-tokens-node-js/

please see server.js and config/passport.js for a walk through the code
https://github.com/Lambda-School-Labs/decisionjam

here is an example of two jwt 
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjaG9pY2VzIjpbXSwiY3JlYXRlZE9uIjoiMjAxOC0wNS0xMFQxMjozMjo1MS45MTJaIiwiX2lkIjoiNWFmNDNiZjNmZmNmNGNmM2JjMjBlMmFjIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJwYXQxIiwiZW1haWwiOiJwYXRlbWFpbDEiLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IiQyYSQxMCR2eERIc2RkckYxZUFDdURIODdTNlFPYlZVcTlPcUtoNmV1cmRkQWpvWTVXbkRFaXRwbGJqYSIsIl9fdiI6MH0.vUcvRiJJD5s8kWBIodbE5ZCQeRdn0r7m6b1pC0KWnYk"

JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjaG9pY2VzIjpbXSwiY3JlYXRlZE9uIjoiMjAxOC0wNS0xMFQxMjo1MjoyNy45MThaIiwiX2lkIjoiNWFmNDQwOGI4MDA2YWJmNGUxZGU5ZmIxIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJwYXQyIiwiZW1haWwiOiJwYXRlbWFpbDIiLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IiQyYSQxMCRTbGhqTHg0aXBlSzRRd2h5T0FSajRPaHZZSWpyWG1rVmFjUjdYL09kMlBpdldoTG5lcUtzSyIsIl9fdiI6MH0.NmZrAupocchKjvwUBblOpLBIFmMujaF2gZ9ii_YfK48"

Answer (score 0):

In req.user is the user saved in session. If you want to take user from JWT token, you should add an authentication method in path declaration, that extract info from JWT token, with jwt.decode  and assing the result to the req.user.
This way user object in request will be the user being authenticated by the token.

Comment: Thanks for the help David . turned out this one was the problem .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706014/node-passport-jwt-extracting-wrong-user-from-token